# What is the purpose of defect limit in Zone D in criteria for MM‐PC Connectors (IEC 61300‐3‐35)

Tags: fiber, optics

Zones in IEC 61300‐3‐35 are defined as shown on this picture.

[image]

However the optical signal is transmitted by the Zone A - Core.

> Light is transmitted and retained in the “CORE” of the optical fiber
>   by total internal reflection.

I do not understand, why there is any limit imposed on defects in Zone D (Contact zone) at all - can it by any means have any real impact on the signal transmission?

Like on this picture of a very dirty old & scratched connector, but no defects within zones A+B and still working.

[image: Really bad connector]

The limit is defined as `Defects - none > 10μm`. Or may be that no defects in Zone A+B means that the picture is not taken properly (there seems to be some noise in background)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all defects are negative. Any protruding defect, or loose contaminant particle, can prevent contact (holding the connector faces apart), scratch the mating connector, or in the case of a loose particle (such as one created by scratching the mating connector) scratch the core.

Comment: I have found out, that 0 defects in zone A are just errors of the measurement procedure, so all the zones are probably equally scratched, but it is difficult to evaluate such a damaged connector as the one on the picture.